# Under what conditions does WITH(rowlock) not work on views?

Tags: sql-server, locking, blocking

We have a lock pileup problem on a customer site. By a combination of tools we managed to locate the root locker. It is definitely running this particular SQL statement at the time of the lock pileup:

```
INSERT INTO #Gather
SELECT (columns omitted for brevity)
  FROM dbo.vScheduleInsuranceRuleViolations WITH(rowlock) OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

Lock hierarchy analysis leads to one unavoidable conclusion: `WITH (rowlock)` isn't doing anything useful here.

The view is very long and rightly takes a long time to evaluate. There are several callers that differ only in there filtering WHERE clause (most of the DB or a few records) and lock/concurrency demand. In this particular caller, we have the worst filter and the lowest lock demand (`WITH (rowlock)` within `READ COMMITTED` -- `READ UNCOMMITTED` won't work here).

Before I copy & paste the view definition into the caller I want to know why this doesn't work if possible; because I'm expecting the `WITH (rowlock)` to apply to every table read in the view.

Comment: Have you considered configuring and testing READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT for the database in your next release?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: Don't call me when tempdb fills up. More to the point, we analyzed that when it came out and found what it would do and it wasn't pretty. Redoing the entire application so it does all validations before writing the first row to the DB and building write order so that observing half-committed transactions is still a close enough to consistent model and using transactions only for the no-commit-half feature wasn't easy but it sure paid dividends in performance.

Comment: "we analyzed that when it came out" Ok, but that was 17 years ago.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: The application is so old it started on SQL 7 and first went into production on SQL 2000. But its nature has not changed even though we have added so many more features. Setting READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT instead of READ UNCOMMITTED overruns tempdb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### starting point

The fun thing about `rowlock` hints is that the storage engine is free to ignore them. From [The Case of the Missing Shared Locks](https://www.sql.kiwi/2010/11/read-committed-shared-locks-and-rollbacks.html):

> One interesting side-effect of the locking optimization described here
> is that a query that takes page locks may block where the same query
> issued with a ROWLOCK hint might not. (I say ‘might not’ since ROWLOCK
> is genuinely a hint, rather than a directive — the storage engine may
> or may not respect it.)
>
> That’s not to say that you should immediately go out and add ROWLOCK
> hints to all your SELECT queries — that would probably be a very bad
> idea — but you should be aware that this locking optimization exists.